# Classes or functions in cypress testing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automation, cypress

Which is considered a better approach for testing in cypress?

Functions:

```
  'support/pages/login.js'
    export const login = (username, password) => {
      cy.get('#username').type(username);
      cy.get('#password').type(password);
      cy.get('#login').click();
    }
    export const verifyHomePage = () => {
      cy.url().should('include', '/dashboard')
    }
  'e2e/login.cy.js'
    it('Test login', () => {
      login("user123", "pass123");
      verifyHomePage();
    })
```

OR:

Classes:

```
  'support/pages/LoginPage.js'
    class LoginPage{
      login(username, password){
        cy.get('#username').type(username);
        cy.get('#password').type(password);
        cy.get('#login').click();
      }
      verifyHomePage(){
        cy.url().should('include', '/dashboard')
      }
    }
    module.exports = new LoginPage();
  'e2e/login.cy.js'
     it('Test login', () => {
       LoginPage.login("user123", "pass123");
       LoginPage.verifyHomePage();
     })
```

Or please mention if you think there's a better way to do these actions?

Comment: For E2E testing in cypress, I prefer to go straight forward approach with testing a feature at least once via UI and then use API's to create the data elsewhere. Of course there will be scenarios that overlap in return I would rather have a small util function sitting in a utils file or support.

Answer (score 1):

Different people will have different preferences, but I will prefer Class over Function in that case. This is why:

- E2E Page Object Model is usually implemented with classes, and it make sense in a big system. [Why to use it](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/cypress-page-object-model), [why not to use it](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions/)
- Class is extendable, so if you have a `LoginForm`, you might want to extend `Form` class that already implements `setInput(selector)` and `clickOk()`, so you don't have to start from scratch
- Class have a constructor, this is a good place to initialize the page and wait until everything rendered, so when you create a class instance in your test, cypress will wait as the constructor will wait for the element to be visible.

A concept example to Page Object with Cypress

```
class LoginForm extends Form {
  constructor(){
    cy.get('.some-page-class').should('be.visible');
  }
  
  login(){
    this.click('.login');
    return this;
  }
  
  setUsername(username){
   this.setInputText('.username', username);
   return this;
  }

  setPassword(password){
   this.setInputText('.password', password);
   return this;

  }
}
```

Then use it in the test

```
describe('Login test', () => {
  it('should login', () => {
    cy.visit('login');
    const loginForm = new LoginForm();
    loginForm
      .setUsername('admin')
      .setPassword('pass')
      .login();
    // assert something
  });
});
```

Comment: What happens to constructor with `module.exports = new LoginPage()`?

Comment: This is something that you probably don't want to do with a class, as it ruins the whole purpose of a reusable class and just create single instance and export it. That called Singleton pattern, which is useful, but might be achieved in a cleaner way. In addition you want to give access to the class itself to be able to create additional instances, inherit it and more.